# Moment JS subtract problems

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm setting up a timer with moment, is not the only one I have in this screen but this doesn't work:

```
const halfBellTimer = () => {
    const x = setInterval(() => {
      let countTime = moment.duration().add({seconds: meditationTime / 2});

      if (countTime <= 0) {
        console.log('STOP');
      } else {
        countTime = countTime.subtract(1, 's');
        console.log(countTime.seconds());
      }
    }, 1000);
  };
```

It sets the time correctly but I get a log of the same value, so it doesn't subtract it.
Any idea?
Thanks!

Comment: Every time the callback is executed `let countTime = moment.duration().add({seconds: meditationTime / 2});` is set. Do you only want to set it once? Then define it outside of the callback.

Comment: thanks. sorry but I don't get it. I want just a countdown that executes something at the end

Comment: Because you are initializing `countTime` inside the callback the value will never decrease.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you move `let countTime = moment.duration().add({seconds: meditationTime / 2});`
outside of setInterval function it works fine.

Don't forget to clean up with `clearInterval`.

Take a look at the example.

```js
const halfBellTimer = () => {
  const meditationTime = 10;
  let countTime = moment.duration().add({
    seconds: meditationTime / 2
  });

  const x = setInterval(() => {

    if (countTime <= 0) {
      console.log('STOP');
      clearInterval(x);
    } else {
      countTime = countTime.subtract(1, 's');
      console.log(countTime.seconds());
    }
  }, 1000);
};

halfBellTimer();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```